# Button does not return action

Tags: java

I want to know, why my Button does not react on clicking. To point is that once I click to the button it should change the background color.

When I set properties of Button in one class it working as expected, however when i try to move properties of Button to another class to make code more clear it returned me only button, without changing the color and without signature of the button.

Where I'm making a mistake?

PANEL:

```
public class ObrazPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public static final int HEIGHT = 200;
    public static final int WIDTH = 200;

    public ObrazPanel() {

    FirstButton FirstButtonTlo = new FirstButton();
    FirstButtonTlo.FirstButton2();
    add(FirstButtonTlo);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    }
```

BUTTON:

```
public class FirstButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

    public JButton backgroundButton;

    public void FirstButton2() {
        backgroundButton = new JButton ("guzikTlo");
        backgroundButton.addActionListener(this);
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension (ObrazPanel.HEIGHT, ObrazPanel.WIDTH));

    }   
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == backgroundButton)
            setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    }   
    }
```

Comment: `FirstButtonTlo`is not linked to the listener. `FirstButtonTlo.backgroundButton`is.

Comment: @jhamon it's just a variable name. We suggests to Tomasz to never start a variable name with upper letter.

Comment: Why are you creating a second button within the first?

Comment: What do you mean Pamasich ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you add a Button `FirstButtonTlo` to your panel. But you add the listener to another button, not displayed on your GUI: `backgroundButton`.

Instead of creating another useless button in the class `FirstButton`, override the constructor, or add a method to set its property:

```
public class FirstButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

    public FirstButton () {
        super();
        this.setText("guzikTlo");
        this.addActionListener(this);
        this.setPreferredSize( new Dimension (ObrazPanel.HEIGHT, ObrazPanel.WIDTH));
    }

// same thing but with a method to initialize the button
//    public void myInitMethod() {
//        this.setText("guzikTlo");
//        this.addActionListener(this);
//        this.setPreferredSize( new Dimension (ObrazPanel.HEIGHT, ObrazPanel.WIDTH));
//    }   

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == this)
            JPanel parentContainer = (JPanel) ((JButton)source).getParent();
            parentContainer.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }   
    }
}
```

Then you can add it to the panel:

```
public ObrazPanel() {

    FirstButton firstButtonTlo = new FirstButton();
    // uncomment if you want to use the method, else do nothing
    // firstButtonTlo.myInitMethod();
    add(FirstButtonTlo);

}
```

Note that instead of the ActionListener, you can use a [MouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

### Side note:

Please try to use Java naming convention: variable name should not start with a capital letter. At first glance, I though `FirstButtonTlo` was a class instead of a variable. Read more here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Thanks Jhamon. Much appriciate.

Comment: however that code changing button color , not background behind the button.

Comment: Either pass it to the button during initialisation and keep it as an attribute, or set the listener to listen on action on the panel instead of the button

Comment: not understanding, can you write the correct code please  ?

Comment: @TomaszKostrzewski I edited my answer: once I check the event source is the button, I get its container (the parent, assuming it's a JPanel) and change the background of this container

Comment: one more thing. in first button class in your code there is no commend to create button , but even though it is created. how come ?

Comment: You may want to have a look on a java course about inheritance.  `FirstButton` **extends** `JButton`, hence FirstButton is a JButton. And is create by calling the `super()`method in the constructor